# How to exclude end of lines of textfiles via terminal?

Tags: sed, grep

Given a file `./wordslist.txt` with `<word> <number_of_apparitions>` such as :

```
aš toto 39626
ir 35938
tai 33361
tu 28520
kad 26213
...
```

How to **exclude the end-of-lines digits** in order to collect in `output.txt` data such :

```
aš toto
ir
tai
tu
kad
...
```

Note :
`Sed`, `find`, `cut` or `grep` prefered. I cannot use something which keeps [a-z] things since my data can contain ascii letters, non-ascii letters, chinese characters, digits, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
cut -d " " -f 1 wordslist.txt > output.txt
```

Or :

```
sed -E 's/ [0-9]+$//' wordslist.txt > output.txt.
```

Comment: need to cut at *last* space, not first.

Comment: Then try this with GNU sed: `sed -E 's/ [0-9]+$//' wordslist.txt > output.txt`.

Comment: I came to use `sed  -r 's/ [0-9]+$//g' wordslist.txt`, which works.
Let's test yours for fun :D
Oh ! Cool. Works too !

Comment: @Hugolpz use `-E` instead of `-r` for portability to OSX sed.

Answer (score 1):

Use awk for print first word in this case.

```
awk '{print $1}' your_file > your_new_file
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` solution to simply print input line excluding last column

```
$ awk '{NF--; print}' wordslist.txt 
aš toto
ir
tai
tu
kad
```

**Note:**

- This will only work in some awks. Per POSIX incrementing NF adds a null field but decrementing NF is undefined behavior (thanks @EdMorton for the info)
- This doesn't check if last column is numeric and field separation in output will be single space only
- If there can be empty lines in input file, use `awk 'NF{NF--}1'`

Comment: That will only work in some awks. Per POSIX incrementing NF adds a null field but decrementing NF is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The following works :

```
sed  -r 's/ [0-9]+$//g' wordslist.txt
```

Comment: Use `-E` instead of `-r` for portability to OSX sed.